# HDAT2 Bad sector fix performs so freaking long

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors, freedos, dban

I have old laptop with os boot related issue. It wasn't booting previously installed windows 10 so I decided to install Linux Mint 20 instead. But something went wrong. I've got `I/O error at /dev/sda` and I thought that it have to be the hard drive issue. I've restarted laptop, run Linux Live CD and after some new kerner exceptions and warnings it finally booted.

I wanted to perform `badsector` fix after `smartctl` check but `fdisk -l` never found and HDD. Next I've used `GParted Live` but it also didn't found any HDD. I was so confused so I thought that whiping the HDD using `dban` will be a good idea (if it find any hard drive, it will be a success). So was doing that freaking cleaning, but new **exception** occured. I've some logs here.

```
DBAN logs:
[2020/08/25 23:15:04] dwipe: notice: Program loaded.
[2020/08/25 23:15:04] dwipe: notice: Opened entropy source '/dev/urandom'.
[2020/08/25 23:15:04] dwipe: info: Device '/dev/sdb' has sector size 512.
[2020/08/25 23:15:04] dwipe: warning: Changing '/dev/sdb' block size from 4096 to 512.
[2020/08/25 23:15:04] dwipe: info: Device '/dev/sdb' is size 320072933376.
[2020/08/25 23:15:05] dwipe: error: main: open: No medium found
[2020/08/25 23:15:05] dwipe: warning: Unable to open device '/dev/sr0'.
[2020/08/25 23:15:05] dwipe: notice: Invoking method 'DoD Short' on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/25 23:15:05] dwipe: notice: Starting round 1 of 1 on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/25 23:15:05] dwipe: notice: Starting pass 1 of 3, round 1 of 1, on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/25 23:41:17] dwipe: warning: dwipe_static_pass: The size of '/dev/sdb' is not a multiple of its block size 4096.
[2020/08/25 23:41:17] dwipe: error: dwipe_static_pass: fdatasync: Input/output error
[2020/08/25 23:41:17] dwipe: warning: Buffer flush failure on '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/25 23:41:17] dwipe: notice: Finished pass 1 of 3, round 1 of 1, on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/25 23:41:17] dwipe: notice: Starting pass 2 of 3, round 1 of 1, on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 00:04:32] dwipe: warning: dwipe_static_pass: The size of '/dev/sdb' is not a multiple of its block size 4096.
[2020/08/26 00:04:32] dwipe: error: dwipe_static_pass: fdatasync: Input/output error
[2020/08/26 00:04:32] dwipe: warning: Buffer flush failure on '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 00:04:32] dwipe: notice: Finished pass 2 of 3, round 1 of 1, on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 00:04:32] dwipe: notice: Starting pass 3 of 3, round 1 of 1, on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 00:47:22] dwipe: warning: dwipe_random_pass: The size of '/dev/sdb' is not a multiple of its block size 4096.
[2020/08/26 00:47:23] dwipe: error: dwipe_random_pass: fdatasync: Input/output error
[2020/08/26 00:47:23] dwipe: warning: Buffer flush failure on '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 00:47:23] dwipe: notice: Finished pass 3 of 3, round 1 of 1, on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 00:47:23] dwipe: notice: Finished round 1 of 1 on device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 00:47:23] dwipe: notice: Blanking device '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 01:11:17] dwipe: warning: dwipe_static_pass: The size of '/dev/sdb' is not a multiple of its block size 4096.
[2020/08/26 01:11:18] dwipe: error: dwipe_static_pass: fdatasync: Input/output error
[2020/08/26 01:11:18] dwipe: warning: Buffer flush failure on '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 01:11:18] dwipe: notice: Verifying that '/dev/sdb' is empty.
[2020/08/26 01:11:18] dwipe: error: dwipe_static_verify: fdatasync: Input/output error
[2020/08/26 01:11:18] dwipe: warning: Buffer flush failure on '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 01:11:18] dwipe: error: dwipe_static_verify: read: Input/output error
[2020/08/26 01:11:18] dwipe: error: Unable to read from '/dev/sdb'.
[2020/08/26 01:11:20] dwipe: notice: Wipe finished.
[2020/08/26 01:11:20] dwipe: notice: Wipe of device '/dev/sdb' incomplete.
```

I thought hmm, I've no idea what gone wrong. Another I/O exception? Maybe caused by CPU overheating (I've got so many events with that warning, or because HDD is just broken) or it was just a bad sector issue.

Next I've found FreeDOS 1.2 bootable Image, copied/pasted `HDAT2 7.0` program to fix, installed it on my USB device, and actually laptop is performing **HDAT2 Bad Sector Check and Fix in Verify/Write/Verify mode**.

After night, I've come to the see results but it checked only *2.89MB* in *8:16h* and any of these checked sectors are marked as `bad sector` with **Uncorrectable Data Error** or **Address Mark not found.** warning. After some calculations I realized that this operartion will take ~100 years to complete because the hard drive has 320GB capacity. And I don't have so many time.

I really want to find a way to fix it, so if you know what should I do instead of waiting 100 years I will be thankful.

#### Update 1

Here is a newly generated S.M.A.R.T log file.

```
*******************************************************************************
HDAT2 v7.0 (c) 2020 CBL  26.08.2020 11:18:26
*******************************************************************************
Detect using SMART error logs [WDC WD3200BEVT-60A23T0]
*******************************************************************************
Device parameters:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Model         : WDC WD3200BEVT-60A23T0
Device        : SATA
Serial number : WD-WX61A80P6659
Firmware      : 02.01A02
Device sectors: 625,142,448 [320.07 GB]
Sector size   : physical 512 bytes = 1 logical x 512 bytes
ATA CHS       : 16383/16/63
Current CHS   : 16383/16/63
BIOS CHS      : 1023/255/63
BIOS sectors  : 16,434,495 [8.41 GB]
DPT CHS       : 16383/16/63 (not valid)
DPT sectors   : 625,142,448 [320.07 GB]
Max. LBA mode : 48-bits
Cache size    : 8.39 MB
SMART         : enabled, status: ERROR
ATA major ver.: ATA/ATAPI 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
ATA minor ver.: not reported
Mode supported: Ultra DMA 5/ATA100
Mode active   : Ultra DMA 5/ATA100
Translation   : LBA
Base unit size: decimal
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test parameters:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name of test    : Detect using SMART error logs
Used commands   :
1. READ         : AHCI/DMA [48-bits]
Test buffer size: 1 sector(s) [0.51 KB]
Number of passes: 1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start time: 26.08.2020 11:18:28.850

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMART error logs                         LBA count       Sectors count
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Summary SMART error log                  0               0
Comprehensive SMART error log            0               0
Extended Comprehensive SMART error log   50              50

Testing 50 sectors with 50 LBA's:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. LBA 5,930-5,930 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. LBA 5,931-5,931 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. LBA 5,931-5,931 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. LBA 5,932-5,932 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5. LBA 5,932-5,932 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6. LBA 5,933-5,933 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7. LBA 5,933-5,933 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8. LBA 5,934-5,934 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9. LBA 5,934-5,934 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10. LBA 5,935-5,935 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11. LBA 5,935-5,935 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12. LBA 5,936-5,936 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13. LBA 5,936-5,936 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14. LBA 5,937-5,937 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15. LBA 5,937-5,937 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16. LBA 5,938-5,938 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17. LBA 5,913-5,913 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18. LBA 5,914-5,914 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19. LBA 5,914-5,914 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20. LBA 5,915-5,915 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21. LBA 5,915-5,915 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22. LBA 5,916-5,916 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23. LBA 5,916-5,916 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24. LBA 5,917-5,917 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
25. LBA 5,917-5,917 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
26. LBA 5,918-5,918 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
27. LBA 5,918-5,918 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28. LBA 5,919-5,919 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
29. LBA 5,919-5,919 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30. LBA 5,920-5,920 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31. LBA 5,920-5,920 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
32. LBA 5,921-5,921 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
33. LBA 5,921-5,921 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
34. LBA 5,922-5,922 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
35. LBA 5,922-5,922 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
36. LBA 5,923-5,923 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
37. LBA 5,923-5,923 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
38. LBA 5,924-5,924 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
39. LBA 5,924-5,924 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
40. LBA 5,925-5,925 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
41. LBA 5,925-5,925 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
42. LBA 5,926-5,926 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
43. LBA 5,926-5,926 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
44. LBA 5,927-5,927 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
45. LBA 5,927-5,927 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
46. LBA 5,928-5,928 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
47. LBA 5,928-5,928 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
48. LBA 5,929-5,929 READ VERIFY SECTORS EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
49. LBA 5,929-5,929 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Uncorrectable data error (UNC)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
50. LBA 5,930-5,930 WRITE DMA EXT with 1 sector(s)

READ: Address mark not found

End time: 26.08.2020 11:21:53.230
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of errors:

READ    : 50

Elapsed time: 00:00:03:24.380
```

Comment: I'd try swapping out the SATA cable & if it looks just as slow, throw out the drive.

Comment: You didn't post the S.M.A.R.T data from `smartctl -a /dev/sda`, but it's highly likely the platters have physical damage _(it would have been listed under the main S.M.A.R.T data, listing the address space the damage is at, the time and date it occurred, and how many times it has been damaged - if it's a high number, the drive is likely not worth saving)_. It could be a bad SATA cable like @Tetsujin mentioned, with the S.M.A.R.T data showing whether it's a physically damaged drive.

Comment: I've updated post with these logs.

Comment: You posted the wrong log. Your log does not contain the SMART parameters which are crucial for judgement compared to your error logs. 
Use smartmontools running smartctl -a /dev/sdX > mylog.txt 
Replace "X" by the drive label in question. mylog.txt will then contain what's needed.

You can't fix broken sectors anyway.